# Typescript build failure

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I'm currently having two projects with typescript 1.1 that are opened in visual studio 2013 with typescript 1.8 installed. VS asks to upgrade which I did but now I get the following error:
Unknown compiler option 'listemittedfiles'.
Anyone has had the same?

Comment: This might resolve your issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/651

Comment: Already found and checked, doesn't seem to be the issue on my end.

Comment: From the command line do: `tsc --version`. What version does this return?

Comment: Returns version 1.0.3.0 :(

Comment: Also fixed my path now so it points to typescript from npm. However my answer also fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems inside the project we had this line hardcoded

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" />
```

That way even though it was upgraded to 1.8 it still tried to use w/e was installed in that folder.
(This is a very old project that needs maintenance...)

Next to that I've removed the hardcoded path in the Path system environment variables so that tsc.exe now points to the NPM version.

Answer (score 2):

If the above answer doesn't work for you, I suggest to take a look to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40370645/1233379) which addressed that same issue on **Visual Studio 2015 Update 3** and above:

(to summarize it, installing TypeScript 2.0 [from this official link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593) might fix the messed-up *MSBuild* cfg and solve the issue).

Comment: Installing this Typescript 2.0 download for VS 2015 actually fixed my VS 2013 issue with `listEmittedFiles`.  Also make sure to remove `<TypeScriptToolsVersion/>` from your .csproj entirely and VS2013 should begin to use Typescript 2.0 compiler which supports `listEmittedFiles`