# How to solve "Build:Unknown compiler option 'listemittedfiles'." on visual studio 2015 update 3?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-2015

After updating the NuGet Type Scripts packages, I was facing with one common build error problem "tsc.exe exited with code 1". After searching I have found the solution how to resolve it. As suggested I installed another two NuGet packages named Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler and Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild. After installing those the tsc.exe exited with code 1 problem solved. But in the mean time a new problem arise on build "Unknown compiler option 'listemittedfiles'".

I was trying to solve it by the suggestion of this [Typescript build failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913705/typescript-build-failure).

But still there has no improvement of this problem.

Can anyone be able to provide a solution please? Please take a lots of thanks in advance.

My client project structure is looks like the image [Please click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQyRv.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build:Unknown compiler option 'listemittedfiles'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39782968/buildunknown-compiler-option-listemittedfiles)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you to try to fix this issue by installing **TypeScript 2.0.6** using the following link:

- [Visual Studio 2015 TypeScript Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593) (2.0.6 at the time of writing)

This will also point MSBuild to the proper TypeScript build, which fully supports the `--listEmittedFiles` command switch.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40370645/1233379) and/or [this blog article](http://www.ryadel.com/en/typescript-fix-ts5023-build-unknown-compiler-option-listemittedfiles-error/) I wrote on this topic for further details and references about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the some problem. I found out, that I had a wrong (i.e. older) version of typescript installed (in addition to the current one) and even though the latest version was installed too, the old typescript compiler (tsc) was used.

Open a windows console and run the command following command:

```
tsc -v
```

The result should be:

```
Version 1.0.1.0
```

If you have the latest typescript installed but don't see the version above, you probably have older versions of typescript installed, that may be the cause of your problems. Uninstall the older versions via "Programs and features" in the control panel of windows.